# vncserver mouse and keyboard not working

Tags: vnc, tightvncserver, vncviewer

Installed vncserver on ubuntu server. When running vnc from root (ssh) everything works fine. When I use a different username (user), the keyboard and mouse do not work (the desktop loads properly). In the vnc logs I found this https://pastebin.com/y86R5F2T .

```
(xfsettingsd:145535): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: 13:44:17.339: XI is not present.
 
(xfsettingsd:145535): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: 13:44:17.339: Failed to initialize the Xkb extension.
 
(xfsettingsd:145535): xfsettingsd-CRITICAL **: 13:44:17.339: Failed to initialize the Accessibility extension.
Failed to connect to session manager: Failed to connect to the session manager: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed
 
(xfce4-session:143733): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 13:44:17.462: ICE connection 0x55d4229ee920 rejected
xfce4-panel: Failed to connect to session manager: Failed to connect to the session manager: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed
 
(xfce4-session:143733): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 13:44:17.473: ICE connection 0x55d4229ee920 rejected
xfwm4-Message: 13:44:17.583: Unsupported keyboard modifier '<Super>Tab'
 
** (wrapper-2.0:145716): WARNING **: 13:44:18.184: No XRANDR extension found
 
** (wrapper-2.0:145715): WARNING **: 13:44:18.202: Binding 'XF86AudioLowerVolume' failed!
 
(wrapper-2.0:145715): pulseaudio-plugin-WARNING **: 13:44:18.202: Could not have grabbed volume control keys. Is another volume control application (xfce4-volumed) running?
 
** (wrapper-2.0:145715): WARNING **: 13:44:18.203: Binding 'XF86AudioPlay' failed!
 
(wrapper-2.0:145715): pulseaudio-plugin-WARNING **: 13:44:18.203: Could not have grabbed multimedia control keys.
 
(wrapper-2.0:145717): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:44:18.205: g_file_new_for_path: assertion 'path != NULL' failed
 
(wrapper-2.0:145717): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 13:44:18.205: g_file_monitor_file: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
 
(wrapper-2.0:145717): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 13:44:18.205: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
 
(wrapper-2.0:145717): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 13:44:18.205: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
 
(wrapper-2.0:145717): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:44:18.205: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkToggleButton to a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, but the widget is already inside a container of type XfcePanelPlugin, please remove the widget from its existing container first.
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/0) is not owned by us (uid 1001), but by uid 0! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
 
(wrapper-2.0:145717): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:44:18.311: Negative content width -3 (allocation 1, extents 2x2) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkToggleButton)
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/0) is not owned by us (uid 1001), but by uid 0! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
```